# Determine whether data is json or string and perform logic basing o that

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

Basically I'm trying to determine whether server returned json or just string

and then convert that json and display its every element in loop or just display that one string.

I'd want to reach something like that:

- Send post request with some data
- If post bodyText contains { and } then parse it as json and draw `<li>` in html

else

- just print bodyText.

---

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {

            user: {
                UserLogin: 'test',
                UserEmail: 'test',
                UserPassword: 'test'
            },
            responseArr: []
        },
    methods: {
        submit() {
            this.$http.post('http://api.com/validate', this.user)
            .then(response => {
                return "OK";
            },
            error => {  
                    return error.bodyText; 
            })
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);

                if (data.includes("{")) {
                    console.log("if");
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    const arr = [];
                    for (let key in data) {
                        arr.push(data[key]);
                    }
                    this.responseArr = arr;
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("else");
                    const arr = [];
                    arr.push(data);
                    this.responseArr = arr;
                }
            }
            );
        },
    }
    });
```

---

```
<div id="errorList">
    <li v-for="element in responseArr">
        <div v-if="responseArr.includes('{')">
            <ul class="errorScope">
                <li v-for="nested_element in element">{{nested_element}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div v-else>
             <li>{{element}}</li>
        </div>
<button v-on:click="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You could just call `JSON.parse()` and catch an exception if one is thrown.

Comment: @Pointy I tried that in "previous versions" but at the end for some reason I'm still unable to inject data into html properly. e.g vue ain't refreshing it.

Comment: Instead of `data.includes("{")` you can do `if (typeof data === "string")` means you got string and do `JSON.parse(data)` in if block

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT this part works properly, but for some reason displaying has problem with " Property or method "element" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. " in 
        <div v-else>
             <li>{{element}}</li>
        </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you parse the response, the response is always string. Problem is you don't know the response is ordinary string, or it is intended to be parseable string. So, you have two options. First, something like this:

```
...
.then(response => {
  let type = 'json'
  let data
  try {
    // try to parse the response text
    data = JSON.parse(response)
  } catch {
    // no, response is not parseable
    data = response
    type = 'string'
  }
  // here you know the type
  // and your data are prepared
})
```

Or, you have second option based on your library you are using for $http calls. Maybe this library can tell you the response type, wheteher it is 'text/plain', or 'application/json'.

PS: If you are unsure if response is already parsed, you can check it this way:

```
if (response instanceof Object) {
  // response is already parsed json string,
  // so object or array
} else {
  // response is not parsed,
  // try to parse it or what
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **typeof** operator to determine if something is Javascript object or not --

```
let obj = {'age' : 30};
if(typeof obj == "object"){
   // It's object
}else if(typeof obj == 'string'){
   // It's String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way of doing it

```
// HTML
<div id="app">
  <h2>Todos:</h2>
  <ol>
    <input type="button"
          v-on:click="load()" value="load next">
    <h1 v-if="textResponse">{{textResponse}}</h1>
    <h1 v-if="loadNr==1" style="font-size: 0.8em">click again to load json}</h1>
    <li v-for="todo in todos">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"
          v-on:change="toggle(todo)"
          v-bind:checked="todo.done">
        <del v-if="todo.done">
          {{ todo.text }}
        </del>
        <span v-else>
          {{ todo.text }}
        </span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>

// CSS
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

li {
  margin: 8px 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

del {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

// JavaScript

const requestText = 'request returned a text response';
const requestJson = '[{"text":"Learn JavaScript","done":false},{"text":"Learn Vue","done":false},{"text":"Play around in JSFiddle","done":true},{"text":"Build something awesome","done":true}]';

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [],
    textResponse: '',
    loadNr: 0
  },
  methods: {
    toggle: function(todo){
        todo.done = !todo.done
    },
    load: function(){
        let requestResponse;
      this.textResponse = '';
        if (!this.loadNr) {
        // simulate text
        requestResponse = requestText;
      } else {
        //  simulate json
        requestResponse = requestJson;
      }

      let json;
      try {
        if (typeof requestResponse === 'object') {
            //  server sent already parsed json
            this.todos = requestResponse;
        } else {
            //  server sent json string
            this.todos = JSON.parse(requestResponse);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        this.textResponse = requestResponse;
      }
      this.loadNr++;
    }
  }
});
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/eywraw8t/242280/)

Comment: What i meant by that is that the api/service that provides the data and sits in between the server and frontend can return json. I rarely deal with json strings. Its almost always json object because thats how intermediate api services are made.